# how to create a text in the footer with JSON in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json

I need to know how I can create a string with the following appearance: "For further questions please contact IT@test.com".
I want to format it with a JSON in the SharePoint Online.

Here is my code so far:

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "text-align": "left",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "border-top-width": "1px"
},
"children": [
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "height": "15px",
            "width": "100%",
            "color": "#fff",
            "font-size": "13px",
            "border-top": "5px solid #eee",
            "background-color": "#F66F6F",
            "padding": "10px"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "Test",
    "attributes": {
        "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
                "mailto:",
                "[$Email]",
                "?subject=Task status"
                
                        ]
                }
                }
                
                }

        ]

     }

 ]
}
```

I only get a hyperlink, but without the text before that.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your code for testing .You can use the following JSON to create a text in the footer.

Full code:

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "text-align": "left",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "border-top-width": "1px"
},
"children": [
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "height": "15px",
            "width": "100%",
            "color": "#fff",
            "font-size": "13px",
            "border-top": "5px solid #eee",
            "background-color": "#F66F6F",
            "padding": "10px"
        },
        "children": [
         {
              "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "For further questions please contact "
         },
            {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "IT@test.com",
    "attributes": {
        "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
                "mailto:",
                "[$Email]",
                "?subject=Task status"
                
                        ]
                }
                }
                
                }

        ]

     }

 ]
}
```

Screenshot of test results:
[image]

Best regards,

Zella Zhang

Comment: Hi Matthias, I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved. If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.